# sandbox paypal ipn not being called since july 15

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

My sandbox ipn not being called from july 15 as it was working fine before that. It is working fine with ipn simulator.

I don't know what went wrong as I didn't make any changes to my ipn as well as paypal form files.

This is my paypal form

```
<form name="frmSample" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sreeni_1342691311_biz@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Memorex">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="25">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="30">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/notify.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

This is only what I wrote in my ipn listener

```
<?php
mail("sreeni@gmail.com","My Subject","My biz Message");
?>
```

the mail is sending while thru ipn simulator. I have tried by changing my business account and also by turning on ipn but nothing works

Could anybody help me? Can anybody check sandbox ipn is working for you?

Comment: This is a known bug for Sandbox at this time that's being resolved as we speak. I suggest you keep trying; it should resume working soon.

Comment: as u said it is working now after a long time. thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem.. However you can notice that its working with the buy now button with
    cmd=_xclick

its just the issue with 
    cmd=_cart

It might be a problem with sandbox only. If you go live it might start working normal.